# SQL Server Report Builder: Field values are getting swapped in Query designer

Tags: sql-server, report, builder

I have a stored procedure which I am calling in my SQL Server report. When I run the stored procedure in the database, I get the correct output. All columns are returning the correct data.

But when I run the same stored procedure in Report Builder's query designer, the column's data is getting swapped. For example, if there are 5 columns in the stored procedure output, in query designer I am getting 1st column value in 2nd column and so on.

Please suggest if there is any issue with query designer.

Thanks

Comment: Well what query are you running in each place, and what is the column order you specify (are you even specifying an order, or just doing `SELECT *` perhaps) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, provide your query for us. It might be an issue with a query. I'd take a look at this firstly. I guess you probably didn't specify column names with alias.

Comment: Yes, You are right, I have actually missed providing aliases for column names. it works fine with alias. Thanks alot.